How do we calculate the md5 checksum of a package inside node_modules in Angular 11?
I have a requirement where I need to calculate md5 checksum for a package residing in node_modules. That package is our organization specific (not a standard angular library).
Path of the package is something like this:

node_modules@xyz\lib-module\abc.jar

I was trying to do in app.component.ts using ts-md5 package. But i am not sure if thats a right approach. Should we do at build level?
Please help me with the approach?
